# Select where two column values are not equal

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to select rows where values from two columns are not equal.

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.numvotes, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.id) AS numvotes
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON
    (t1.id = t2.id)
GROUP BY t1.id
```

The data from `t1` is:

```
  id    |   numvotes
 -------------------
  1     |   4
  2     |   6 
  3     |   1
  4     |   3
  5     |   2
```

The data from `t2` is:

```
 id
-----
 1 
 1
 1
 1
 2
 2
 2
 3
 4
 4
 4
 5
```

The results from the above query would be:

```
  id    |  numvotes  |  numvotes
 -------------------------------
  1     |  4         |  4
  2     |  6         |  3
  3     |  1         |  1
  4     |  3         |  3
  5     |  2         |  1
```

Now, I want to modify the MySQL query to only SELECT where the numvotes from `t1` is different from the calculated COUNT DISTINCT value from `t2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done in the `HAVING` clause. `WHERE` filters before `GROUP BY`, `HAVING` after `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.numvotes, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.id) AS numvotes
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.id) <> t1.numvotes
```